# How to redirect system out print to FileAppendar in apache log4j

Tags: xml, apache, logging, log4j

I have successfully implemented log4j for my application, all logs are written in a file.Now, I have some System out which I have wanted to be printed in the same log file.Here is what I have till now

```
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4Vj.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
<!-- general application log -->

<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
                <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
                    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %30.30c - %m%n"/>
                    </layout>
         </appender>
        <appender name="default" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
                <param name="File" value="${log.dir}/logs/debug.txt" />
                <param name ="Append" value="TRUE"/>
                <errorHandler class="org.apache.log4j.varia.FallbackErrorHandler">
                        <root-ref/>
                       <appender-ref ref="console"/>
                 </errorHandler>
                <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{[HH:mm:ss:SSS]|[MM-dd-yyyy]} [%c] %p - %m%n"/>
                </layout>
                <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB"/>
                <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="100"/>
        </appender>

<logger name="ioreactorlog" additivity="false">
                <level value="INFO"/>
                <appender-ref ref="default"/>
        </logger>

        <root>
                <level value="INFO"/>
                <appender-ref ref="default"/>
                <appender-ref ref="console"/>
        </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Is it possible to write some of console out to debug.txt?

Answer (score 0):

Use the configuration file to add `debug.txt` as the target of the `FileAppender`:

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <file value="debug.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <layout type="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```